# How do I make parameters mandatory in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How do I make parameters mandatory in PowerShell?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You specify it in an attribute above each parameter like this:

```
function Do-Something{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $aMandatoryParam,
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $anotherMandatoryParam)

    process{
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What's nice is you don't have to even specify the '=$true' part if you don't want to.  'Mandatory' is a switch parameter so its presence in the decorator signifies its value of '$true'.  Also if you prefer, you can explicitly set it to false.

Comment: You don't have to specify `Position` when you have it in the default order...

Comment: I did not pursue this but I believe the Comment Based Get-Help only picks up the mandatory attribute if you use the (Mandatory = $true) form.

Answer (score 32):

To make a parameter mandatory add a "Mandatory=$true" to the parameter description. To make a parameter optional just leave the "Mandatory" statement out.

This code works for both script and function parameters:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [String]$aMandatoryParameter,

  [String]$nonMandatoryParameter,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [String]$anotherMandatoryParameter

)
```

Make sure the "param" statement is the first one (except for comments and blank lines) in either the script or the function.

You can use the "Get-Help" cmdlet to verify the parameters have been defined correctly:

```
PS C:\> get-help Script.ps1 -full
[...]
PARAMETERS
    -aMandatoryParameter <String>

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    1
        Default value
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?

    -NonMandatoryParameter <String>

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    2
        Default value
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?

    -anotherMandatoryParameter <String>

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    3
        Default value
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?
```

Comment: just curious, what happens when lets say a .BAT calls a .PS1 and a mandatory parameter is left out. what does the PS1 response/error look like?

Comment: When you call a PowerShell script without providing the mandatory parameters the script prompts you for them interactively before executing, e.g. "Supply values for the following parameters: aMandatoryParameter:"

Answer (score 19):

just wanted to post another solution, since i find `param(...)` blocks kind of ugly.
looks like this code:

```
function do-something {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $First,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Second
    )
    ...
}
```

can also be written more concisely like this:

```
function do-something (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $First,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Second
    ) {
    ...
}
```

which looks much nicer! the `=$true` can be omitted because `mandatory` is a switch parameter.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to specify `Mandatory=true`, `Mandatory` is enough.

Simple Example:

```
function New-File
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$FileName
    )

    New-Item -ItemType File ".\$FileName"
}
```